# How do I run wine with bubblewrap?

Tags: wine, sandbox

I am trying to run Windows games with wine and bubblewrap so that they are sandboxed. When I run the command below:

```
bwrap \
    --ro-bind /bin /bin \
    --ro-bind /lib /lib \
    --ro-bind /lib64 /lib64 \
    --ro-bind /root /root \
    --ro-bind /run /run \
    --ro-bind /sys /sys \
    --ro-bind /sbin /sbin \
    --ro-bind /usr /usr \
    --ro-bind /etc /etc \
    --dir /tmp \
    --dir /var \
    --proc /proc \
    --dev /dev \
    wine
```

I get `bwrap: execvp wine: No such file or directory`. However, if I change `wine` to `ls /usr/bin/win*` I can see that wine is clearly there. `/usr/bin/wine` doesn't work either.

Most of my other programs, like bash, seem to work. I'm guessing I'm missing some arguments to `bwrap`, but what?